# Spring Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW) error com.sun.proxy.$Proxy60

Tags: java, spring, annotations, spring-batch, transactional

using Spring batch , I have a class contains 2 methods. one of them has Transactional annotation.
When trying to run the batch I get an error :
Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:com.sun.proxy.$Proxy60

context.xml :

```
<batch:job id="data-update" parent="raptorBaseJob">
    <batch:step id="load-info" parent="raptorBaseStep">
        <tasklet ref="loadInfoTasklet" />
     <batch:next on="COMPLETED" to="update-info" /> 
    </batch:step>

    <batch:step id="update-info" parent="raptorBaseStep">  
     <tasklet ref="updateInfoTasklet" />  
    </batch:step>
</batch:job>
```

loadInfoTasklet.java :

```
@Component
public class LoadInfoTasklet implements Tasklet {

@Autowired
private InfoManager infoManager;

@Trace
@Override
public RepeatStatus execute(StepContribution stepContribution, ChunkContext chunkContext) throws Exception {    
    try {
        infoManager.load();     
    } catch(Exception ex) {
        stepContribution.setExitStatus(new ExitStatus("FAILED_LOADING"));
    }
    return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
 }
}
```

updateInfoTasklet.java :

```
@Component
public class UpdateInfoTasklet implements Tasklet{

    @Autowired
    private InfoManager infoManager;

    @Trace
    @Override
    public RepeatStatus execute(StepContribution stepContribution, ChunkContext chunkContext) throws Exception {
        try {
            infoManager.update();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            stepContribution.setExitStatus(new ExitStatus("FAILED"));
        }
        return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
    }
}
```

InfoManager.java :

```
@Component
public class InfoManager {

@Autowired
private NameInfo namesInfo;

protected List<String> names;

  @Trace
  public void load() throws Exception {
      names  = namesInfo.getNames();
  }

  @Trace
  @Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public void update() {
        System.out.println("Updating...");
    }
}
```

Full stack error msg :

> 12:40:54.071 [main] ERROR o.s.b.c.l.s.CommandLineJobRunner - Job
>   Terminated in error: Error creating bean with name 'loadInfoTasklet':
>   Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not
>   autowire field: private InfoManager LoadInfoTasklet.infoManager;
>   nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set
>   infoManager field LoadInfoTasklet.infoManager to
>   com.sun.proxy.$Proxy60

Comment: You need to display the full stacktrace.

Comment: Could be a classloader issue. It's trying to inject `infoManager` to `LoadInfoTasklet`, but failing. The stacktrace however doesn't show much useful information, but if `$Proxy60` is a `InfoManager` proxy and the assignment fails, I'd suspect class loading issues.

Comment: When a class has the `Transactional` annotation, it needs to be proxied, because Spring need a place to put the code which begins/commits the transaction. The most common use is with an `EntityManager`, and in that case the `EntityManager` is actually a Proxy which interacts with the transaction through ThreadLocal state where the current `EntityManager` is stored. Since InfoManager is not an Interface, a Proxy will not work (but I would have expected Spring to use CGLIB to proxy a concrete class)